# UserControl x Form - Cancelar evento da tela após validação do UC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu tenho um UserControl, que faz um validação no evento Validated, e na tela, eu tenho o botão Confirmar.

Quando eu utilizo o atalho ALT + C, para executar o evento do botão, irá executar a validação do evento Validated, e após isso o evento do botão.

Tem como eu "cancelar" o evento do botão, quando der erro na minha validação no UserControl?

Não sei se ficou muito claro, o que eu estou tentando fazer. Caso esteja meio confuso, segue abaixo "prints" para melhor entendimento:

UserControl:

[image: UserControl]

Código fonte no form:

[image: Form]

Quando eu clico no botão Confirmar na tela, ele funciona certinho.

- Executa primeiro a validação do Validated, e retorna. E não executa a mensagem que está no botão "Confirmar"

Como falei acima, se executar pelo atalho ALT + C, irá acionar os dois eventos.

Alguém tem alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: Como você está associando o atalho ALT + C ao evento do botão?

Comment: Marcus, bom dia!

Então, o texto do botão ele esta com o "&" para que eu possa utilizar a combinação de ALT + C.

Texto do botão esta assim &Confirmar.

Comment: Olá, por favor, não poste uma print do seu código na pergunta, coloque ele mesmo (como: inicie cada linha do código com quatro espaços no início)

Answer (score 1):

O [Evento Control.Validated](http://Evento%20Control.Validated) somente será chamado após perder o foco.

O seu código só funciona porque você sempre devolve o foco ao controle `textbox` após o evento de validar, porém, ao acionar o ALT+C além de tirar o foco do text (e fazer a validação) ele ainda executa o código do botão confirmar.

Se por exemplo, você clicar no form e clicar no botão confirmar, ele não fara a validação, somente executará o código do botão confirmar.

Faça como no exemplo abaixo que vai funcionar.

**Código no UseControl**

```
public partial class MyTextBox: UserControl
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void ValidaTexto()
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("a"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de Validação - Não executar evento...");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Validação OK!");
    }
}
```

**Chamada no Form**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextBox.ValidaTexto();
    }
```